# Frame content not appearing in Firefox

Tags: firefox, markup, frames, frameset

This simple frameset is not working in Firefox (IE7, 8, Chrome is okay).  `main` doesn't appear but `footer` does.  There's a frame window divider flush to the top of the screen, but even after pulling that divider down, no `main` content is shown.

It's validated under its DOCTYPE.  Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
  </head>
      <frameset rows="*,33">
          <frame name="main" src="internalpage.html" />
          <frame name="footer" src="http://www.example.com/externalpage.html" />
      </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Might not matter, but since you obviously tried it and it failed, why not indicate what Firefox version and what OS you tried it under?

Comment: Very weird.  @Bert F ... I'm sporting a Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out it was Ad Block Plus.  I've enabled it on Firefox to test whether certain Ajax calls were getting through, and forgot it was there.

I've had another problem with Ad Block Plus in the past:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482385/adblock-is-killing-my-xmlhttprequests-work-around

Funny program: kills the free internet, messes up xmlhttprequests, and blocks frame content pulled from a localhost.  Boo Ad Block Plus